# Can't get discord.py to raise an error if user doesn't have permissions to kick

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a quick bot that can kick people if it has the permission to do so and the user has the permission to do so as well as raise an error in chat if either the bot doesn't have the permissions or the user. However my current solution doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code that handles it, the code works to kick people when you have the permissions but doesn't raise an error if the bot or the user doesn't have the permissions.

```
@client.command(name = 'kick', pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(kick_members = True)
@bot_has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def _kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason='No Reason Given'):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} was kicked for {reason}')


@_kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = (f'Sorry {ctx.message.author}, you do not have permission to do that')
        await ctx.send(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions required for this command.")
    return

  raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your error is in the order of the parameters. This works for me:

```py
@_kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'Please pass in all requirements {ctx.message.author.mention} :rolling_eyes:.')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You dont have all the requirements {ctx.message.author.mention} :angry:")
```